# Google translate Text-to-speech action canceled

Tags: javascript, audio, google-translate

I have write a function who gets the audio element from Google Translate:

```
Interface.prototype.say = function( text ) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src ='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=fr&q=' + escape( text );
    audio.play();

    console.log( audio.src );
}
```

`audio.src` returns the right string to translate but It didn't say anything. In console, in Network section I found that:

```
translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=fr&q=Initialisation%20termine
translate.google.com
GET
(canceled)
Pending
game.php:1
Parser
```

As you can see, the file request was canceled. If I click on the link (first line), it works very well. It seems that it's not working only when I try to request the file to another domain, but it works perfectly in the Google Translate domain.

What is the problem?

---

Solution:

```
Interface.prototype.say = function( text ) {
    var section, frame;

    section   = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ];
    frame     = document.createElement( "iframe" );
    frame.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=fr&q=' + escape( text );

    section.appendChild( frame );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an Iframe to the SRC. It will play automatically, or set an onload handler for the audio that then calls `play`. It's likely because you're forcing it to play before it has downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it works very well with an iframe. I've added the solution in the question.